# Windows, ClearCase, and Ant: how to handle directory slashes?

Tags: windows, ant, clearcase

I have a Windows batch script  that I use to build a module and the script in turn uses the ClearCase `clearmake` command to drive the actual compilations, directory creations and file manipulations, i.e. process the Makefile content.  The batch script works flawlessly when invoked using a DOS window or from a "cmd /c ..." command line invocation.  And it has been that way for some number of years.

I recently decided to move the script to Ant.  The first step, out of simplicity, was to simply invoke the script unchanged using an *Exec* task (using `cmd /c`).  Almost immediately, Ant fails while creating a directory.  The error message reports something like:

`mkdir: Cannot create the directory C:\\fred\\harry\\joe`

I was able to verify that, using the DOS command prompt, the `mkdir C:\\fred\\harry\\joe` command works fine, so, as near as I can tell so far, Ant generating double backslash path separators combined with something inherent to `clearmake` and/or something in the Makefile is causing the failure.

The response I'm looking for is something along the lines: "Yes, `clearmake` is definitely the culprit because..." or "If you twiddle this thing or that thing in Ant, only a single backslash will be generated...".  Should there be no simple and quick explanation, I will drill into the problem to determine what exactly is causing the failure.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I have seen similar error with:

- dynamic views (more sensible to ownership than a snapshot view on C:\, which is your case)
- resource handle conflict (the script tries to update a resource already taken by another process, which shouldn't be the case here with your script, since it was working outside of Ant Exec task)
- error message (like you create a directory which already exists: the error get ignored in a classic script, while it could interrupt the ant task.

While the last cause is a good candidate, try first to simplify your script (leave only the `mkdir` for instance) in order to check that this line is indeed the issue (nd not "this line in conjunction with others actions taking place just before")